# How to set outputs on a Toshiba TC62D722CFNG shift register LED driver IC

Tags: pwm, led-driver, shift-register

I want to use the [TC62D722CFNG](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/408/TC62D722CFNG_datasheet_en_20180509-1372050.pdf) shift-register LED driver IC to toggle some LEDs, however, I am having trouble getting the outputs to turn on at all. The IC is capable of controlling the LED current via a PWM signal, but I am just interested in turning the outputs on/off for now.

From my understanding of the datasheet, the S2 command should be sufficient for this.

[image: S2 command]

I input the data via SIN and CLK followed by TRANS="H" while inputting 7 more clock pulses.
I used an oscilloscope to verify that the signals are correct, but the outputs stay off.

The shift registers' SOUT signal is also correct, so I don't believe that this is a hardware issue.

Here's the block diagram from the datasheet:

[image: block diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to chapter 2.3.2 in the datasheet the S2 command (ON/OFF) only enables or disables the previously configured PWM feed to the outputs.

As long as there is no PWM configuration, this will enable the output with PWM zero, so still off.

The default state is "enabled" anyway, so this function call has no effect after chip power on.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to input the PWM reference value to the register 3 (datasheet page 19). After that I am able to control individual outputs via the S2 command, followed by a PWM signal on PWMCLK.